# Passat B5 door will not unlock

Tags: electrical

English from Google translate:

Hi, how can the front door be unlocked by lifting the button, the button does not stay up but is tense and goes down. The padding is taken and the door's inner stain as well, I get the lock close but the lock can't get loose.

The story started, so that one day the first doors did not open in the remote control, but only the rear and then climbed from behind, and the driver's door was unlocked by pulling the link twice. From the remote, only the rear doors are closed and the first doors do not react. the driver's seat open and the front passenger stuck in position.

[Orignal text in Estonian]

Tere, kuidas on võimalik kõrvalistuja uks lukust lahti saada, nupust tõstes ei jää nupp üles vaid on pinges ja läheb alla tagasi. polster on võetud ja ukse sisemine plekk samuti, saan lukule ligi kuid lukustust ei saa lahti. Alguse sai see lugu nii et ükspäev esimesed uksed ei avanenud puldist, vaid ainult tagumised ja siis sai tagant ette ronitud ja juhiuks tuli lukust lahti kaks korda linki tõmmates. Puldist lähevad vaid tagauksed kinni ja esimesed uksed ei reageeri. juhioma lahti ja kõrvalistuja kinni kiilunudasendis.

Comment: Hi Indrek, welcome to the forum. I guess we don't have many people here who can read Estonian, so I added an English translation to your question.

Comment: I've done an additional edit to update the title to english and the put the english version first so it will be visible in the truncated display on the question list.